# Can't open subdirectory with Opencart

Tags: opencart, subdirectory

I have a problem with opening my subdirectories. I have Opencart installed in the root of my server. I have some other subdirectories with other things like scripts and pages. When i try to open them, i get the custom 404 Opencart page. Even when i direct to url/subdirectory/index.php or so.

Comment: I could not find the sub category, Example Ball, Big Ball, Red Ball, **** would not show when I types "Ball, Big Ball " it would only show the top category, But when I started typing Red ball or *** it showed the sub category How this help someone, Took me an hour to work out, try editing code and alot of reading,,

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the last rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- it is redirecting any URL not containing the question mark (`?`) to that OpenCart router which fails to route the URL and falls into 404 default page.

For Your case to work You would have to add `RewriteCond` and test that the path does not contain the name of the subdirectory(ies).

For example, You would like to run scripts in `/<OC_ROOT>/my_subdirectory/...`, add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(my_subdirectory)\/.*
```

Should it be another `your_subdir` and `his_subdir`, You could add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(my_subdirectory|your_subdir|his_subdir)\/.*
```

Make sure the last rule goes after this condition:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(my_subdirectory|your_subdir|his_subdir)\/.* # <- OUR NEW COND
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I didn't test the condition thus hope it will work.